# Difference between <% and <%=

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb

Can somebody tell me what is the difference between the `<%= %>` and `<% %>` tags in erb? In which case should I use which one? What other tags can I use and what is their meaning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As said

```
<% %>
```

will take the ruby code inside and evaluate it

```
<%= %>
```

will take the ruby code inside and evaluate it and print the result on the screen, which generally means will return a printable result which can be used in html as normal text

so doing

```
<div class="<% 'myclass' %>">
```

will result in

```
<div class="">
```

and `<div class="<%= 'myclass' %>">`
will result in

```
<div class="myclass">
```

you can see this railscast which explains it further
http://railscasts.com/episodes/100-5-view-tips

Also, you will probably encounter this in the future and even forget I wrote this but it might be useful anyhow

in some cases, not every line of ruby code should be a line of <% %>. 
for example - using a case switch

this won't work:

```
<% case my_var %>
<% when 10 %>
<% some ruby code %>
<% end %>
```

but this will

```
<% case my_var 
  when 10 %>
<% some ruby code %>
<% end %>
```

so be wary of that

Answer (score 1):

`<%= %>` is used when you want your executed ruby to be output to screen, that means anything written inside this block gets printed in your output screen,

where as `<% %>` block is used to perform your ruby logic part, for eg your `if` condition, `loop` statement, etc..

Answer (score 1):

```
<% %>
```

Executes the ruby code within the brackets.

```
<%= %>
```

Prints something into erb file.